# Cascading waveforms onto a single variable in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 3 signals:

```
a = ecg(1000);  // clean ecg with no noise
b = a + noise1; // with noise component on the ECG
c = a + noise2; // a,b,and c have the same dimension (1000x1)
```

now, i want to put the concatenated signal onto a single variable, x, so that the output of x would be:

```
x = a concatenated with b; b concatenated with c;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cascading"? Do you mean **concatenating**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by cascading you mean **concatenating**, simply do this:

```
x = [a b c];
```

This simply pieces `a`, `b` and `c` together so that they are one signal and the three signals are side-by-side each other.  Doing `ecg(1000)` creates a `1 x 1000` vector.  Assuming your noisy signals after that respect the same dimensions, then the above syntax should hold.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, concatenating is the proper term. =)